# How can PyMC3 handle uncertainty in the number of parameters in a Dirichlet Distribution?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, python, hierarchical-bayesian, pymc

I'm taking a look at the following to familiarize myself with Bayesian Inference in PyMC3:

https://towardsdatascience.com/estimating-probabilities-with-bayesian-modeling-in-python-7144be007815

In this, the author talks about going to the zoo and seeing a specific number of each of three distinct species, and modelling the prior distribution of seeing any particular species on a given day using a Dirichlet Distribution. This sounds reasonable to me.

But what if we don't know how many species there are? I.e. we see a chimp and a monkey and might consider them the same or different species, depending on how good of a look we get at them. This would impact the number of parameters use for the Dirichlet Distribution, but how do we handle a variable number of hyperparameters?